# Perl awk regex differs to standard regex?

Tags: regex, awk

```
int abc0/0.1
int abc0/1
int abc0/1.2
```

I'm using [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) to create a regex rule that will match a line if there is a '.' near the end of the line. I have the following rule:

```
int [A-Za-z]*[0-9/]*\.[0-9]*
```

which works perfectly in regexr but it doesn't work when using it with awk. Is there some differences I need to know about?

This is the line I am using. It's worked fine on previous, simpler matches, just not this one.

```
`awk -v RS=! -v ORS= '/int [A-Za-z]*[0-9/]*\.[0-9]*/{print FILENAME}' file`;
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the intent of `RS=!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `regexp`. There's only `regexp for tool X`, where `X` is your tool of choice. There are some general guidelines for regexps, but every tool has caveats and its own rules for which flavors of regexp it uses and how to specify them.

For example, `/` is a RE that matches a forward slash but try using `/` in a regexp context in awk or sed:

```
sed '///' file
awk '///' file
```

and both will fail with syntax errors since the `/` char is also a regexp delimiter and so literal `/`s need to be escaped while with grep on the other hand:

```
grep '/' file
```

it will work just fine. Every tool has it's own caveats and many tools have multiple ways of specifying the same regexp, none of them being exactly the same way as other tools.

This might robustly be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '/int [[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]/]*\.[[:digit:]]/' file
int abc0/0.1
int abc0/1.2
```

but the RE you posted should have worked just fine:

```
$ awk '/int [A-Za-z]*[0-9/]*\.[0-9]*/' file
int abc0/0.1
int abc0/1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `/` inside the regex:

```
awk -v RS=! -v ORS= '/int [A-Za-z]*[0-9\/]*\.[0-9]*/{print FILENAME}' file
```

Comment: I had tried that previously and neither worked. It's still matching lines without the '.' in it. So in the above example it matches the second line as well as the others.

Comment: Test it as `awk '/int [A-Za-z]*[0-9\/]*\.[0-9]*/' file` to see which lines it matches. It matches line 1 and line 3 only

Comment: @DJDMorrison when you tested previously you must have forgot to escape the `.`.

Comment: @anubhava no, you don't need to escape `/` within a character set.

Comment: @EdMorton: On gnu-awk you don't need to escape `/` within character class but on my OSX's awk it is needed to be escaped.

Comment: @sln you are correct for sed, wrong for awk in general. Even old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris) is just fine with `echo "a/b" | /usr/bin/awk '/[/]/'` outputs `a/b`, though OSX awk, nawk and /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (just tested those last 2) treat it as a syntax error for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

no standard for regex. if you have to ask, the original regex has only 3 meta character: `.`, `*`, `?`. the rest characters represent themselves. regex varies, but after perl came out, it gradually took the majority of the "market" and the engines after it always try to be compatible with perl's. therefore, you will see a noun "perl compatible regex syntax", but it's still not a standard.